# Try to add values to List<Integer>

Tags: android, database, list, sqlite

when I tried to add some values to my List inside my onResume() method i got this error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {.../...MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3127)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2482)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5415)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
        at de.toeducate.tograde.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:151)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6237) at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3085)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2482)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5415)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:725)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
```

and here is the code I wrote:

```
List<Integer> marks = Collections.emptyList();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataBase.getDataMark().size(); i++) {
        marks.add(dataBase.getDataMark().get(i).getValue());
    }
```

What does this mean?

Comment: you use a function (`emptyList`). did you wondered what it does before asking that question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is literally in the first line of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections.emptyList()` returns an instance of `AbstractList`. This is meant by the line

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
```

in your exception's stack trace. This said you cannot call `add` on your `marks` list as `add` is not implemented.

Instead instantiate `marks` with a class that allows for adding elements, such as `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Besides `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` is another implementation of `AbstractList` that supports adding elements. Most typically programmers use an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 5):

`Collections.emptyList();` returns a `List` that you cannot add to (hence the `UnsupportedOperationException`).

Use

```
List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

instead.